# UIWebView loadData won't show adsense

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, loaddata

I'm loading a remote html page using:

```
[myWebView loadData:xmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Everything is showing fine except adsense ad.
But when I tried this line:

```
[myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Adsense is showing fine, but I'd like to use loadData.

How can I fix this please?

Thanks

Comment: Could I know why do you prefer to use `loadData`?

Comment: Because I noticed that it's faster than loadRequest.